# Feedforward Fully Connected Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am doing some research regarding Feedforward Fully Connected Neural Network's and is thus searching for some literature regarding this topic - however I have some difficulties finding such specifically for Feedforward Fully Connected Neural Network's.

Can anyone suggest some good articles/books for my purpose?

Thanks.

Edit: Still searching. I need the mathematical background for a supervised Feedforward Fully Connected Neural Network.

Answer (score 0):

This seems strange. Feed-forward fully connected neural networks are the most common, basic type of neural network out there, as far as I know (unless you want to talk about the perceptron).

If you're looking for a book, you can consider *Neural Networks and Deep Learning: A Textbook*, by Charu C. Aggarwal. But for such a basic topic there are other resources too, such as this [this free online book](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/).

Comment: I would like to have some mathematical details regarding the Feed-forward fully connected neural networks. I have failed to find such books/articles. I am gonna take a look at your two suggestions.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "mathematical background". The two books I mentioned will describe mathematically how the network makes predictions and how it learns the weights.